# Equalizer: How can i get the current active audio session id?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an equalizer that applies to the current audio source (music, youtube, soundcloud... any app using the audio basically)

But for this I need to select an Audio Session Id, to initialize the Equalizer() object.

Before setting it to 0 was working for all the sources, but this is no longer the case on the most recent devices.

**Any idea on how to get the current active audio session id ?**

Comment: Hi, did you get any way to do this?

Comment: No I did not succeed, and haven't tried since

Comment: so I can assume that you haven't tried any further? :) / :(

Comment: Nope sorry => :(

Comment: And you still haven't?  There is an app that does exactly that https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devdnua.equalizer&hl=en, so we can definitely say _there is a way_. But I had not luck trying to figure that out.

Comment: I do not believe you have a very similar name to mine and asked the same question 3 years ago, hehe... Well, maybe it is so outdated, but this is the point I have arrived: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62984951/1593550