# Get Audio Session Id from Google Meet

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audiosession

I am playing with [`DynamicsProcessing`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/DynamicsProcessing). I want to process the audio from an external application. I just require the `audioSessionId` for that. I have no problems with **Play Music**, for example. I have used a `BroadCastReceiver` listening the `android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION` and everything works like a charm.

```
<receiver android:name=".framework.AudioSessionReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

```
class AudioSessionReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        intent?.let {
            val audioSessionId = intent.getIntExtra(Equalizer.EXTRA_AUDIO_SESSION, -1)
            val packageName = intent.getStringExtra(Equalizer.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME)
            KLog.i("audioSessionId: $audioSessionId")
            KLog.i("packageName: $packageName")
        } ?: KLog.w("Intent is null")
    }
}
```

The challenge is when I want to do the same with **Google Meet**. I do not know how to get the session id from the app. But I know it is possible because I can see it directly if I look for it on Logcat:

```
WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: [623:191] [21746] AudioTrack: session ID: 7649, channels: 1, sample rate: 48000, max gain: 1.0
```

And I have checked it works if I pass the `session ID` (audioSessionId) manually.

**How can I do it from the app?**

Thank you so much!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It can be obtained from the `audioSessionId` of the active `AudioRecord` because it is created just after the `AudioTrack` creation and the numbers go from 8 to 8.

```
val audioManager = (context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager)
return audioManager.activeRecordingConfigurations[0].clientAudioSessionId - 8
```

I have checked it doing a video conference with **Google Meet** and equalize the voice from the other person. ;-)

https://github.com/soygabimoreno/AudioClean